# How can I handle this kind of exceptions (in Doctrine)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Can you tell me how can I handle this kind of exceptions:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine_Connection_Exception' with
>   message 'PDO Connection Error:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection
>   to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 110' in ...

It happens when connection with MySQL is lost during query. I need to handle this exception so I can show 500 error page so the crawlers do not cache page, and to redirect user to appropriate "Try again" page.

P.S. I have a lot's of code, so I can not go trough all code to put try/catch block. I need something simple and yet effective.

Comment: Are you using a framework? Most frameworks implement some sort of ErrorController which eventually catches all exceptions during the dispatch loop and directs them to the appropriate error page.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it with Zend Framework. But, I really don't know how error messages got in Google cache. When something is wrong during predispatch, ZF returns 500. But this, it beats me. I've read some docs about Doctrine, and I found this: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en#connection-listeners but, I don't know how to implement it. :(

Answer (score 1):

> I need something simple and yet
>   effective

**try/catch** will be your only choice IMO. If you have to many places where you need to add a try/catch clause, you could move this particulat piece of code into a seperate function.

If, say, this line throws the execption

$con->query($your_DQL_query)
//something happends here with the results

move it to an something like

```
function goodQuery($sql) {
  try {
    $con->query($sql);
  } catch (Doctrine_Connection_Exception $dce) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

You still need to replace all of your "throwing" methods with a call to function  `goodQuery(...)` but this will make future development easier since the exception is handled in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't handle it with Doctrine... You handle with your coding language. If you're using PHP:

```
try {
  SomeClass::do_something(parameter);
} catch(DoctrineException $e) {
  show_error($e->getMessage());
}
```

This is obviously sudo-code, but it gives you an idea... You could show a general error or be specific and display doctrine's message...

Comment: Thanks. I'm OK with exceptions, but I can't go trough thousands of lines of code to implement try/catch everywhere... I'm not building nuclear reactor, just a simple website where I can say "I'm sorry :(" when something gone wrong.

Comment: I mean, you can throw the errors and catch them in your application controller if you're using a framework